# T-SQL: How can I order individuals with multiple rows by minimum Rank but keep their rows grouped together?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, report, rank

I'm creating a committee roster report. I have a few hundred rows of data in which I have Name and Position, and each Position has a set Rank, where the lower it is, the higher the Position’s standing in the committee.

I need to sort the VIPs to the top by their most important (lowest) Rank position first and if they have any other positions in the committee, I need those to sort right after that in the list in ascending Rank order, followed by the next best ranking position VIP and their other Positions in ascending Rank order.

Then--after around Rank 100 or so--the list of Positions that are considered VIP ends, so I just want everyone to sort by Name then Rank from then on.

Here's a model of the kind of data I'm trying to sort with it organized in the way I'm hoping for:

| RANK | POSITION | NAME | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chair | Jane J. | 10009 |
| 3 | Treasurer | Jane J. | 10009 |
| 9 | Editor | Jane J. | 10009 |
| 2 | Vice Chair | Kevin K. | 10002 |
| 5 | Director | Kevin K. | 10002 |
| 3 | President | Laura L. | 10003 |
| 4 | Vice President | Manuel M. | 10005 |
| 10 | Asst. Editor | Manuel M. | 10005 |
| 100 | Member | Anna A. | 10010 |
| 100 | Member | Ben B. | 10014 |
| 50 | Coordinator | Carry C. | 10020 |
| 100 | Member | Carry C. | 10020 |
| 60 | Asst. Coord. | Dennis D. | 10008 |
| 61 | Mbr. Coord. | Dennis D. | 10008 |

Below is a simplified model of the SELECT statement I'm currently working with, which does not accomplish what I'm looking for. I've tried a lot of custom columns in my attempt to make the custom sorting I'm looking for possible, but none have helped.

```
SELECT
RANK
, POSITION_CODE
, LAST_FIRST

FROM Table

ORDER BY RANK, LAST_FIRST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT

MIN(RANK) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS MinRank
, RANK
, POSITION_CODE
, LAST_FIRST
, ID

FROM Table

ORDER BY MinRank, RANK, LAST_FIRST
```

Edit: Using my new **MinRank** calculation, I can now first `ORDER BY` a committee member's Position (POSITION_CODE) with the lowest number RANK (lower numbers for a Position being of greater standing in my committee). This puts the top-ranking Position committee member at the top the top of the list and ascends through everyone else's MinRank, causing the list to sort blocks of names with the same minimum RANK positions together. Then I can `ORDER BY` RANK ascending, which will sort those blocks in themselves with lesser standing RANK positions. Lastly, I can `ORDER BY` their names (LAST_FIRST) so that each block of RANK-sorted MinRanks is in alphabetical order by last and first name. For a bonus distinction if needed, I can also `ORDER BY` ID at the end, to differentiate between those with the same first and last name.

The `OVER (PARTITION BY ID)` of my `MIN(RANK)` aggregate is just a shortcut so I don't have to put all my properties into a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30241717)